# Package PGF Math Error: (internal routine) for tikz picture in semilogxaxis (Bode diagram)

Tags: tikz-pgf

and many thanks for being alive.

I try to make the Bode Diagram of a function, and following error appears (for both functions in log10 and atan).

My code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{semilogxaxis}[
  ylabel=$G_\textrm{dB}$ (en $\mathrm{dB}$), 
  xmin={1}, xmax={1e2}, 
  ymin={0}, ymax={20},
  grid=both,
  minor y tick num=2,
  major grid style={black!50},
  width=1.0\linewidth, height=.3*\linewidth
  ]
\addplot[domain=1:1e2,color=black, smooth, samples=100] {
  -10*log10((1-(\x/100)^2)^2+(2*0,4*\x/100)^2)
};
\end{semilogxaxis}

\begin{semilogxaxis}[
  xlabel=Fréquence $f$ (en $\mathrm{Hz}$), 
  ylabel=Phase (en $^{\circ}$), 
  xmin={1}, xmax={1e2}, 
  ymin={-100}, ymax={100}, 
  minor y tick num=2, 
  grid=both,
  major grid style={black!50},
  width=1.0\linewidth, height=.3*\linewidth, yshift=-175
  ]
\addplot[domain=1:1e2,color=black, smooth, samples=100] {
  -atan((2*0,4*\x/100)/(1-(\x/100)))
};  
\end{semilogxaxis}
  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The error I get :

*! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit
got an ill-formatted floating point number `0Y0.0e0]1Y4.0e-2]'. The unreadable
part was near '0Y0.0e0]1Y4.0e-2]'. (in '20*log10(1.0000000000)+10*log10(1+(1.0
000000000/150)^2)-10*log10(1+(1.0000000000/5)^2)-10*log10((1-(1.0000000000/100)
^2)^2+(2*0,4*1.0000000000/100)^2)').*

If somenone got an idea.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!!. Change the comma decimal separator for a dot: `\addplot[domain=1:1e2,color=black, smooth, samples=100] {-10*log10((1-(\x/100)^2)^2+(2*0.4*\x/100)^2)};` and the same in the other function